# Pass variable via link_to action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My view:

```
<div class = "btn btn-link">
  <%= link_to 'Generate Rating Set', {
    :controller => "co_view_rating", 
    :action => "generate_rating_set_co_view" } %>
</div>
```

This links to a action in my controller which creates a new record. How can I pass a variable via this method in my view to the action in my controller. The variable would be user input via a text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send your variable through a form with the `POST` method.

```
<%= form_tag('/co_view_rating/generate_rating_set_co_view') do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'my_variable' %>
    <div class="btn btn-link">
        <%= submit_tag "Generate Rating Set" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And in your controller action :

```
def generate_rating_set_co_view
    my_variable = params[:my_variable]
end
```

you can find more documentation on form_tags and input types here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a form if the user input comes from a text field.

```
<%= form_tag {:controller => "co_view_rating", :action => "generate_rating_set_co_view"}, :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :awesome_text_field, "default value" %>
  <div class="btn btn-link">
    <%= submit_tag "Generate Rating Set" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The text input will then be available in the params hash as `params[:awesome_text_field]`.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting what @Sparda said, use a field with post, and pass a  hidden_field (if you want it to be hidden) or a input_tag, or text_field